# How do I get browsermob-proxy to record ALL response bodies

Tags: browsermob-proxy, har, little-proxy

I'm having trouble with browsermob-proxy and its har exporting feature. Some response bodies are not logged (the entire "text" field is missing)

My setup (using browsermob-proxy 2.1.4)

`curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/proxy?port=9091`

`curl -X PUT "http://localhost:8080/proxy/9091/har?captureHeaders=true&captureCookies=true&captureContent=true"`

Some responses are fine:

`"response": {
    "status": 201,
    "statusText": "Created",
    "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
    "cookies": [],
    "headers": [{
      "name": "Cache-Control",
      "value": "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store"
    }, {
      "name": "Content-Type",
      "value": "application/json"
    }, {
      "name": "Date",
      "value": "Thu, 15 Feb 2018 13:07:39 GMT"
    }, {
      "name": "Location",
      "value": ...
    }, {
      "name": "Pragma",
      "value": "no-cache"
    }, {
      "name": "Render-Time",
      "value": "8"
    }, {
      "name": "Server",
      "value": "openresty"
    }, {
      "name": "Strict-Transport-Security",
      "value": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
    }, {
      "name": "transfer-encoding",
      "value": "chunked"
    }, {
      "name": "Connection",
      "value": "keep-alive"
    }],
    "content": {
      "size": 8607,
      "mimeType": "application/json",
      "text": "{ <actual json body> }",
      "comment": ""
  }, ...`

But some are not (maybe it is the special content/mime type? or maybe it is the gzip content encoding?)

`"response": {
        "status": 200,
        "statusText": "OK",
        "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
        "cookies": [],
        "headers": [{
          "name": "Cache-Control",
          "value": "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store"
        }, {
          "name": "Content-Encoding",
          "value": "gzip"
        }, {
          "name": "Content-Type",
          "value": "application/some.custom.type-v1+json"
        }, {
          "name": "Date",
          "value": "Thu, 15 Feb 2018 13:07:39 GMT"
        }, {
          "name": "Pragma",
          "value": "no-cache"
        }, {
          "name": "Render-Time",
          "value": "92"
        }, {
          "name": "Server",
          "value": "openresty"
        }, {
          "name": "Strict-Transport-Security",
          "value": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
        }, {
          "name": "Vary",
          "value": "Accept-Encoding"
        }, {
          "name": "Content-Length",
          "value": "1978"
        }, {
          "name": "Connection",
          "value": "keep-alive"
        }],
        "content": {
          "size": 7429,
          "mimeType": "application/some.custom.type-v1+json",
          "comment": ""
          < there's nothing else here!! >
        },
        "redirectURL": "",
        "headersSize": 444,
        "bodySize": 1978,
        "comment": ""
      }, ...`

Oh yea, both requests are over https, using MITM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer to my own question

In BrowserMobHttpClient.java I found the following:

```
private boolean hasTextualContent(String contentType) {
    return contentType != null && contentType.startsWith("text/") ||
            contentType.startsWith("application/x-javascript") ||
            contentType.startsWith("application/javascript")  ||
            contentType.startsWith("application/json")  ||
            contentType.startsWith("application/xml")  ||
            contentType.startsWith("application/xhtml+xml");
}
```

Looks like I'll have go make a custom build of browsermob-proxy to make it work.

Comment: CyberWiz, What have you changed  ? I am also facing the issue that it does not record Content-Encoding header. Please let me know the change in the BrowserMobHttpClient.java. Thanks in advance

Comment: I just added a line for my particular content type, something like || contentType.startsWith("application/some.custom.type-v1+json")